# Biblatex - style authoryear - author in capital

Tags: biblatex

I use biblatex with the authoryear style and want the author to be printed in my text (when citing) in capital letters, as well as in the bibliography at the end of my article.
Is this possible?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: Do you want all capitals just for family name or all name parts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to format (bits of) names in `biblatex`.

I opted for small caps in the following example because I don't think capital letters will look good.

### Name parts

If you only want to format a particular part of the name (e.g. the family/last name part or the given/first name part), you can redefine  `\mkbibnamefamily`, `\mkbibnamegiven`, `\mkbibnameprefix` and/or `\mkbibnamesuffix` with your desired style.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{sigfridsson,knuth:ct:a}

\printbibliography  
\end{document}
```

[image: "(Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998; Knuth 1984)" only family names in small caps]

### Complete names

Instead of redefining all four macros  `\mkbibnamefamily`, `\mkbibnamegiven`, `\mkbibnameprefix` and `\mkbibnamesuffix` to do the same, it is easier to redefine the macro `\mkbibcompletename` to format the complete name at once.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibcompletename}[1]{\textsc{#1}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{sigfridsson,knuth:ct:a}

\printbibliography  
\end{document}
```

[image: "(Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998; Knuth 1984)" only family names in small caps]

Note how given names are also in small caps in the bibliography.

### The entire field

If you want to format the entire field including delimiters like the comma and 'and', you can use a wrapper format.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{default}{\textsc{#1}}
\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{sortname}{default}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{sigfridsson,knuth:ct:a}

\printbibliography  
\end{document}
```

[image: "(Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998; Knuth 1984)" only family names in small caps]

Note how the 'and' between Sigfridsson and Ryde is also in small caps here.

Comment: Thank you for solving this problem. It has partly solved my problem too. I need small caps in bibliography only, not in citations. Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: New versions have `\mkbibcompletename` to format the entire name at once. Furthermore one could use `\DeclareNameWrapperFormat` if one wanted to format the entire fielod output including delimiters (comma, 'and', ...).