# Italics and regular "et al" for authors and editors respectively

Tags: biblatex, formatting, citing

I am using gost-numeric bibliography style and I have the following issue:
I want et al to be italics or regular depending on its context, i.e.
in my example in italics in author list and in regular in editor list.

Obviously redefining `\renewbibmacro*{name:andothers}`, as it is suggested in [Formatting et al in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/352114/formatting-et-al-in-biblatex) affects both of these in the same way.

How is it possible to make this work?

Update: MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@INCOLLECTION{TatbulPrecisionRecallTime2018,
  AUTHOR = {Tatbul, Nesime and Lee, Tae Jun and Zdonik, Stan and Alam, Mejbah and Gottschlich, Justin},
  EDITOR = {Bengio, S. and Wallach, H. and Larochelle, H. and Grauman, K. and Cesa-Bianchi, N. and Garnett, R.},
  PUBLISHER = {Curran Associates, Inc.},
  ANNOTATION = {00012},
  BOOKTITLE = {Adv. in {{Neural Inf. Processing Systems}} 31},
  DATE = {2018},
  PAGES = {1920--1930},
  TITLE = {Precision and {{Recall}} for {{Time Series}}},
  langid = {english},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
bibstyle=gost-numeric,
blockpunct=space,
otherlangs=true,
citestyle=numeric,
movenames=false,
sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}
\renewbibmacro*{name:andothers}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
    and
    test \ifmorenames
  }
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{1}
       {\finalandcomma}
       {}%
     \andothersdelim\bibstring{andothers}}
   {}}
 \begin{document}
 \cite{TatbulPrecisionRecallTime2018}
 \printbibliography
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a slightly different solution using name wrappers.

I figured that the idea is to have the whole author list (including possible "et al."s) in italics and to format the editor list normally.

`biblatex-gost` already defines a special name format called `heading` for the authors at the beginning of the entry. If we make use of the name wrapper, we can get italics for the entire name list and only need to redefine `\mkbibhdnamefamily` to avoid double italics.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
  bibstyle=gost-numeric,
  citestyle=numeric,
  sorting=none,
  movenames=false,
  blockpunct=space,
  otherlangs=true,
]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{name:andothers}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
    and
    test \ifmorenames
  }
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{1}
       {\finalandcomma}
       {}%
     \andothersdelim\bibstring{andothers}}
    {}}

\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{heading}{\mkgostheading{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibhdnamefamily}[1]{#1}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{TatbulPrecisionRecallTime2018,
  author     = {Tatbul, Nesime and Lee, Tae Jun and Zdonik, Stan
                and Alam, Mejbah and Gottschlich, Justin},
  title      = {Precision and Recall for Time Series},
  editor     = {Bengio, S. and Wallach, H. and Larochelle, H.
                and Grauman, K. and Cesa-Bianchi, N. and Garnett, R.},
  booktitle  = {Adv. in Neural Inf. Processing Systems 31},
  date       = {2018},
  pages      = {1920--1930},
  publisher  = {Curran Associates, Inc.},
  annotation = {00012},
  langid     = {english},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{TatbulPrecisionRecallTime2018}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: "Tatbul N. et al." all in italics]

Name wrappers are a fairly recent addition to `biblatex` (they were added in v3.12 from 2018-10-30). You can find some more examples and how it compares to other possibilities of name formatting at [Biblatex - style authoryear - author in capital](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/445637/35864).

Comment: Thank you! This solution is even more concise than the previous one and also works flawlessly on my original huge document.

Answer (score 3):

For this solution I will use the `xpatch` package but if you want you can do without it.

First of all, let's remove the square brackets:

```
\xpatchbibmacro{name:andothers}{\mkbibbrackets}{}{}{}
```

Then we create the new macros `name:andothers:it` and `name:andothers:rm` and modify the first one so that it prints the string `andothers` in italics:

```
\letbibmacro{name:andothers:it}{name:andothers}
\letbibmacro{name:andothers:rm}{name:andothers}
\xpatchbibmacro{name:andothers:it}{\bibstring}{\bibstring[\emph]}{}{}
```

Finally we make the driver `@incollection` use these two new macros, respectively, before printing the list of authors and the list of editors, translators, etc.:

```
\xpatchbibdriver{incollection}
  {\usebibmacro{author/translator+others}}
  {\letbibmacro{name:andothers}{name:andothers:it}\usebibmacro{author/translator+others}}
  {}
  {}
\xpatchbibdriver{incollection}
  {\usebibmacro{byauthor}}
  {\letbibmacro{name:andothers}{name:andothers:rm}\usebibmacro{byauthor}}
  {}
  {}
```

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
 @INCOLLECTION{TatbulPrecisionRecallTime2018,
  AUTHOR = {Tatbul, Nesime and Lee, Tae Jun and Zdonik, Stan and Alam, Mejbah and Gottschlich, Justin},
  EDITOR = {Bengio, S. and Wallach, H. and Larochelle, H. and Grauman, K. and Cesa-Bianchi, N. and Garnett, R.},
  PUBLISHER = {Curran Associates, Inc.},
  ANNOTATION = {00012},
  BOOKTITLE = {Adv. in {{Neural Inf. Processing Systems}} 31},
  DATE = {2018},
  PAGES = {1920--1930},
  TITLE = {Precision and {{Recall}} for {{Time Series}}},
  langid = {english},
 }
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
bibstyle=gost-numeric,
blockpunct=space,
otherlangs=true,
citestyle=numeric,
movenames=false,
sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibmacro{name:andothers}{\mkbibbrackets}{}{}{}
\letbibmacro{name:andothers:it}{name:andothers}
\letbibmacro{name:andothers:rm}{name:andothers}
\xpatchbibmacro{name:andothers:it}{\bibstring}{\bibstring[\emph]}{}{}
\xpatchbibdriver{incollection}
  {\usebibmacro{author/translator+others}}
  {\letbibmacro{name:andothers}{name:andothers:it}\usebibmacro{author/translator+others}}
  {}
  {}
\xpatchbibdriver{incollection}
  {\usebibmacro{byauthor}}
  {\letbibmacro{name:andothers}{name:andothers:rm}\usebibmacro{byauthor}}
  {}
  {}    

\begin{document}
 \cite{TatbulPrecisionRecallTime2018}
 \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

#### Edit

You can also replace the two `\xpatchbibdrivers` with this:

```
\xpretobibmacro{author/translator+others}{\letbibmacro{name:andothers}{name:andothers:it}}{}{}{}
\xpretobibmacro{byauthor}{\letbibmacro{name:andothers}{name:andothers:rm}}{}{}{}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the solution, Ivan, that worked great!

Comment: I edited the answer: the result is the same, but now it prevents `andothers` from being printed in italics in the lists following `author/translator + others`, which you most likely don't want

Comment: Yes, and also this way I no longer need to patch each driver individually, because basically I need the same with `inproceedings`.

Comment: Also, when I made `et al` italics by default for all publication types with `\DefineBibliographyStrings`, I had to swap `name:andothers:it` and `name:andothers:rm` in your examples.